# Switching to a different fragment while staying in the same tab in a Sliding Tab Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, tabs

I have a Sliding Tab layout with a Recycler View that holds three tabs. The first tab holds a Card View. What is the best way to achieve the following: when you click on a button inside the first card the Card View (a fragment) it is replaced by another Card View (another fragment) while staying in the same tab.

I know I have to create a new fragment and use transaction. I just do not know where. Do I put it in an adapter? If possible I would like to use onClick for the button in the XML Layout for the first Card View.

[Sliding Tab How-to](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-SlidingTabLayout)

[Sliding Tab Layout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java)

[Sliding Tab Strip](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java)

MainActivity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MainFragmentPageAdapterForTabs(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                MainActivity.this));

        // Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager
        SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        // Center the tabs in the layout
        slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);

    }


    public void bodyButtonAction(View view){
        Intent intentBody = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentBody);
    }
```

Tab Fragments:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

// In this case, the fragment displays simple text based on the page
public class MainPageFragmentForTabs extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;

    public static MainPageFragmentForTabs newInstance(int page) {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        MainPageFragmentForTabs fragment = new MainPageFragmentForTabs();
        //body fragment
        Fragment bodyFragment = new MainPageFragmentForTabs();

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);


    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = null;


        if(mPage==1){
            View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment_page, container, false);
            FragmentActivity a = getActivity();

            //recycler
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view1.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            //layout manager
            LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(a);
            manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);


            MainAdapterCV1 ca = new MainAdapterCV1();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(ca);

            view=view1;

        }
        if(mPage==2){
            View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment_page, container, false);
            //stand-in code
            TextView textView = (TextView) view2;
            textView.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
            //stand-in code
            view=view2;

        }
        if(mPage==3){
            View view3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment_page, container, false);
            //stand-in code
            TextView textView = (TextView) view3;
            textView.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
            //stand-in code
            view=view3;

        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Adapter for first Card View:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainAdapterCV1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapterCV1.CardViewHolder> {


    //
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder cardViewHolder, int i) {

    }
    //
    @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.main_card_view1, viewGroup, false);

        return new CardViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        public CardViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the Google sample code Sliding Tab layout also! It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can add or replace a fragment anywhere you want. However doing it in the Adapter, I think, is more logical than inside a fragment. One reason is the adapter normally has the click event listener code, and I don't see it in the posted code, which is fine. Sample code to replace a fragment (using your code):

```
MainPageFragmentForTabs myFragment = MainPageFragmentForTabs.newInstance(page);

FragmentTransaction transaction = thisActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
// Replace the Fragment (set in MainActivity) with this fragment.
transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, myFragment, "MainPage");

transaction.addToBackStack(null);       // support the Back key
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: After looking at apps with tabs (Goodreads and Duolingo), I realized they did not keep their tabs when a user clicks on a button in their main fragment. So, (like them) I decided to only keep the toolbar when I click to a new fragment. No transaction needed. Your answer might still be useful if I need to switch fragments in some other place. There is a high chance of that. Thanks for the info on the adapter!